# Button Paint Pane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I'm trying to add data to my `JTable`. I have the following code which throws no errors but when I run the preview mode and click the button nothing at all happens.

```
Object[][] data = null;
String[] columnNames = new String[2];

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    columnNames = new String[] {"Title", "Author"};
    data = new Object[1][2];
    data[0][0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a book title");
    data[0][1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter author name");
    jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your IDE (so don't add that tag).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you post _all_ the relevant code? We need to see this button and how you are adding a listener to it.

Comment: Posted code looks reasonable, but without knowing the context of how the code is used we can't help. Did you add a printl(...) to the method to make sure it is executed (ie. did you add the ActionListener to the button). Do you have the variable jTable1 defined twice? We are not mind readers, that is why we need a SSCCE.

Comment: this is all my code, http://pastebin.com/je40k1ct thanks

Comment: @user2598957, 1) code should be posted in the forum. 2) how do we execute that code? It is just a panel with no frame.

Comment: I found out I was just running the interface, when I shift + f6 to run the build, I have no main method apparently. How does a gui have the main method...

Comment: *"How does a gui have the main method.."*  That is an entirely different question, which should be *asked on a separate question!*

Answer (score 2):

> [...] but when I run the preview mode and click the button nothing at
>   all happens.

Based on quoted line and your [code](http://pastebin.com/je40k1ct) I suspect you're running the NetBeans GUI Designer preview mode:

[image]

If so then nothing will happen because this option is intended to display the designed GUI but not to interact with it. So you can hit that button all day long without any result. Instead of that you need to display a [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) or [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) with your panel as follows:

```
public class Test {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JPanel bookStoreSystem  = new BookStoreSystem();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");      
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(bookStoreSystem);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Update

> bookstoresystem couldnt be found

Based on your file's tree:

http://puu.sh/66Ooz.png

The problem is `BookStoreSystem` class couldn't be found because of missing import to this class. First off is not a good practice to create classes into the default package, so you should rename this package (let's say to `gui`): right click over the package -> Refactor -> Rename. Second step is adding the right import in `BookStore` class:

```
import gui.BookStoreSystem;
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks I took a read and understand that I need one of the two above to run my code, I added as you suggested but after gui imports I had the following issue - 

My file tree - http://puu.sh/66Ooz.png (may help)

errors - http://puu.sh/66Orl.png

bookstoresystem couldnt be found, and createandshowgui couldn't be referenced from a static context

Thanks!

Comment: I changed it to "private static void createAndShowGUI() {" to remove the 2nd error if that's the right way to go about it

Comment: @user2598957 please see updated answer. To solve the first error see **Update**. To remove the second error see updated code.